How to see HTTP requests made by content script file, Firefox Addon Extension
I started developing a firefox extension.
In my extension I make requests with fetch.
But the requests don't appear in the Network tab of developer tools.
I am opening the developing from within the page where the content script is loaded, like you would debug this page normally.
Console logs do show up though, it's only the requests that do not appear.
If I log the request response, it does show up in the Logs tab.
The issue is that it does not appear in the Network tab.
Any ideas please ?

I found the issue :
I was using manifest v2
In this case, I was supposed to use :
content.fetch(...)
Other option is to upgrade to manifest v3
